# Newly added SharePoint List column is hidden - SPFx WebPart

Tags: spfx, pnp-js

I added list column as below using pnp js and api call is working without issue. but Column is hidden even it is created.
is there any reason for that ?

```
var fieldXML = "<Field Hidden='FALSE' DisplayName='455' Format='Dropdown' IsModern='TRUE' MaxLength='255' Name='455' Title='455' Type='Text'><Default>11</Default></Field>";  

      sp.web.lists.getByTitle("listTitle").fields.createFieldAsXml(fieldXML).then(function (result) {
       //success  
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if list has custom default view on? When you add a column to a list it should be visible in "all items" view but not in custom views unless added.